# how get filenames only copy to other folder using cmd batch file

Tags: cmd.exe

Can anyone teach me how to get only filename using batch file? I need to make a loop to check if it exists in another folder so that I don't have to copy over.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/4228807/4748017

Comment: just use robocopy, it automatically skips duplicates.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In following `FOR` loop you get filename and extension:

```
for %%f in ("C:\Source\*") do ( echo File: %%~nxf )
```

To check if your file exists in target directory and copy if it does not:

```
for %%f in ("C:\Source\*") do (
  if not exist "C:\Target\%%~nxf" (
    echo Copy from source to target: %%~nxf
    copy "%%f" "C:\Target\%%~nxf" )
)
```

For more `FOR` loop parameters, see `FOR /?` in command line.

Comment: It works... you are the best!!!